# Freqtrade OKX "remove volumepairlist or switch to using "candles" "

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

exchange does not support dynamic whitelist in this configuration. please edit your config and either remove volumepairlist or switch to using candles and reset the bot.
when I try to connect my bot it shows this error what should I do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: when i try to connect freqbot to OKX it shows this error: "exchange does not support dynamic whitelist in this configuration. please edit your config and either remove volumepairlist or switch to using candles and reset the bot." what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but i just came across it and found the solution.

The answer is in the documentation for Freqtrade. Certain Exchanges dont provide the correct data to use a Volume based list. You either need to set a Static List, of set a candle data as the exchnce your using does not supply 24h Volume. Or you can set Volume list based on extra data by using candles.

From freqtrade docs:

> On some exchanges (like Gemini), regular VolumePairList does not work as the api does not natively provide 24h volume. This can be worked around by using candle data to build the volume. To roughly simulate 24h volume, you can use the following configuration. Please note that These pairlists will only refresh once per day.

Please check https://www.freqtrade.io/en/stable/includes/pairlists/#volume-pair-list in the 'Unsupported Exchanges' section